# iPhone 4S keeps old numbers in Messages

Tags: ios, contacts, messages

The numbers that are no longer in my contacts still keep popping up when I try to compose a new message.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to purge the contact list so no *already-deleted-contact* remains?

Comment: Just a guess, but do you perhaps have texts from these people still saved in Messages? Perhaps iOS is polling both your contacts and your message history for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have iOS 7 (now) I can provide you the steps on how to remove **Recent** contacts in the **Messages.app**.

1. Open Messages.app
2. Start composing new message
3. Once the list starts showing up, press the **blue 'i' icon** next to the number.
4. Press the redline **Delete from recent**
5. You're done, repeat these steps for the contacts you don't want to show up anymore.

EDIT: Community bumped this thread up making me answer it because I never check the dates. I hope I can still help anyone  out with this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Power the phone off and then on again. That should clear out the bug.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Just updated it.